# Store user input into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, input

I want to get user input in R and store them into dataframe's column which matches. For example:

```
Month Year  Value       No
4     2016  114235.00   A22
5     2016  114235.00   A22
6     2016  114235.00   A22

my.name <- readline(prompt="Year: "))
my.month <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Month: "))
my.off <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Value: "))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
readData <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(Month = c(), Year = c(), Value = c())
  while(TRUE) {
    my.year <- readline(prompt="Year: ")
    # stop reading if no year was typed in
    if (my.year == '')
      break
    my.month <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Month: "))
    my.val <- as.integer(readline(prompt="Value: "))
    # add the read data to the bottom of the dataframe
    df <- rbind(df, data.frame(Month = c(my.month), Year = c(my.year), Value = c(my.val)))
  }
  df
}
# now call the function, it will allow inputs until an empty year is typed
readData()
```

Comment: Perhaps the     `if (my.year == '') break` command should be immediately after the Year prompt, so if the year is blank it does not also prompt for the month and value

Comment: Oh yes, that would be smarter, thanks @Kerry Jackson.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. I missed to tell one thing about my question. I already have a dataframe which contains 8 columns, some of them is above. What I want to do is that I want to store new values from user inputs to this existing dataframe. In this case, how code should be changed?